# How can I Limit or forbid download from my Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Every month we have huge number of data download from our Google storage, when we have only about 4Gb pics and docs.

How to understand who use our storage, who and what download and upload in our storage.

How to fix it?

Here it is the examples of

```
July 2015
Cloud Storage Download US EMEA: 61.511 Gibibytes (Project:API Project) - 7.38
June 2015
Cloud Storage Download US EMEA: 449.487 Gibibytes (Project:API Project) - 53.94
May 2015
Cloud Storage Download US EMEA: 39.645 Gibibytes (Project:API Project) - 4.76
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on [Access Logging](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs?hl=en) which will provide you a log with every access to your data. This will allow you to see who is downloading your data, when.

You can limit who has access by setting up appropriate [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control).